# How can I retrieve data from database in QML?

Tags: database, qt, qml

I am trying to retrieve data from database in QML. The code bellow works in Qt5 but I can't access the data from QML. I get: "undifined". Can anyone help me please?

db.cpp

```
dataB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

dataB.setHostName("192...");
dataB.setDatabaseName("database");
dataB.setPort(123);

dataB.setUserName("user1");
dataB.setPassword("user1");

this->model = new QSqlQueryModel();

model->setQuery("SELECT status FROM telephone");

ui->tableView->setModel(model);//result is in the first image

QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();

QQmlContext *context = view->rootContext();
context->setContextProperty("mySQLmodel", model);

view->setSource(QUrl("main.qml"));
view->show();
```

main.qml

```
Rectangle {
width: 300
height: 300

ListView {
    id: someListView
    anchors
    {
        fill: parent
 }
   model: mySQLmodel
    delegate: Label {
       text:{ "1 " + mySQLmodel.status}
   }

 }}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to create your own c++ model with properties you can access from qml. you can then fill your model from your database.
Take a look at this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html for your model.